# Using integers for registered date claims is deprecated, please use DateTimeImmutable objects instead

Tags: php, laravel

Using integers for registered date claims is deprecated, please use DateTimeImmutable objects instead. This error occurs during generate personal access token using laravel passport @ laravel8.12enter code here.

Comment: this is because "lcobucci/jwt" upgraded to 3.4 with a lot of breaking changes. Downgrading this to 3.3.3 fixes the issue.. In your project `composer.json` add `"lcobucci/jwt": "3.3.3"` and execute `composer update`.

Answer (score 45):

**If you are using `Tymon/jwt-auth`,
this could help you
In `config\jwt.php` file**

```
Change 

'jwt' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWT\Lcobucci::class, 

to 

'jwt' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWT\Namshi::class,
```

Comment: Worked, you may need to call `php artisan optimize` after change to clear cache

Comment: @AshwaniGarg Is that safe to do? Even though this solution (just a workaround solution) fixes the issue, are you certain about changing `Lcobucci` to `Namshi` would not be any issue for the `jwt token issuing function` to work as expected?

Comment: It worked in my case, you have to test your token after using this solution.

Answer (score 19):

Run the below command to fix this issue.

```
composer require lcobucci/jwt:3.3.3
```

Answer (score 6):

I think there is an issue with icobucci/jwt:3.4... just run `composer require lcobucci/jwt:3.3.3` it should work..

Comment: Ran into the same problem, your solution worked, spared me some headaches :)

Answer (score 2):

This also happens with tymon/jwt-auth ^v1.0

If that happen, you can also switch to the Namshi provider, specified in the jwt.providers.jwt configuration of tymon/jwt-auth.